# Typescript does not recognize that a promise has been fulfilled in my Promise.all

Tags: javascript, typescript

I currently have a setup where I initiate a couple of asynchronous requests and await Promise.all() of them at the end. Typescript however still thinks the promise has not been fulfilled yet.

Example:

```
const Promise1 = someAsync()
const Promise2 = someAsync()
const Promise3 = someAsync()
await Promise.all([Promise1, Promise2, Promise3])
console.log(Promise1.someData) // is a problem
```

I suppose I could await for Promise1 again in the console log but that seems a bit patchy, any ideas? or am I wrong about Promise1 being resolved at the console.log point?

Comment: `Promise1` is still a promise, it hasn't changed from being a promise ... `const [someData, result2, result3] = await Promise.all([Promise1, Promise2, Promise3])` .... now `someData` is the resolved value of `Promise1`

Comment: @JaromandaX after using solely async/await for 2 years I kind of developed the assumption that when a promise resolved, it resolved into the data without having to retrieve said object from promise

Comment: You clearly don't understand promises as that is never the case.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I was mistaken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to await the resolved values in the return value of [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). A [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) itself will never have a `someData` property:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4G4BQaBmBXAdgYxgEsJc4BnCAW2AEFyBPAuACgEpE0459Tz4owctgA28ALyJKNACIBDGHIBccALIKAFgDooc3ABNq7VFziCY2KGQAKUakXLAdQiCIBuwFoOFi26JBi8uPxwYHZUDsAAjHCS0nSMBOzoQSFh9o4ATLEU1AlM+MloqfDpEY4AzDnx9AVFcgDuckTwthlOciIiLADaZZFRADSh4ZGZw-2VALpsxXyuTiIQAOYsk9Fa8fKKfnAA9ABUcADqRF1wS8twAAZ4+sCYRLjA+tdwAEbA+HLYjkqm3EBQOBwIAfuCIeC0G0wMBYAw4AByLYKOSIuCGIRwXAQeCgBzwUhwGAMWFItrlYAAHgQuVkqJUuGwVE+UBQcCQAD5EVoWJkKhUAJwcA57DB7PZwACSwRgwDk+mGjWa8BgGmAZhc7hecDcnWwQn+JTgPW8rg8+iGmso2v042t5peFSmOWVLTgFMiWk63T6o0cVvW9vWztmqQWWkuXi1Fqimzy2zkfgBINTQIlAD0APxoIA)

```html
<script type="module">

function someAsync () {
  const result = {someData: Math.random()};
  return Promise.resolve(result);
}

const promise1 = someAsync();
const promise2 = someAsync();
const promise3 = someAsync();
await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
console.log(promise1.someData); /* Will log `undefined` because:
                     ~~~~~~~~
Property 'someData' does not exist on type 'Promise<{ someData: number; }>'.(2339) */

// Instead, await the resolved values:
const [resolved1, resolved2, resolved3] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
console.log(resolved1.someData);
                    //^? (property) someData: number

</script>
```

Comment: I cannot believe I forgot about this lol, its been a while since I've had to wait for multiple promises to complete. I think my problem was when I was testing, I tried console.log((await promise1).someData))